# Issue downloading files with WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webclient

Tested WebClient on both project type (WPF,Windows form application)
With the below code:

```
String[] txt = { "someURLstring", "otherURLstring" };
foreach (String str in txt)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
    await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(str), "somename.rar");
    }

}
```

Both projects are developed using Visual Studio 2015 with .net framework 4.5 on windows 10.
The issue is that, when those applications are not running on the PC that they are developed, the files that are downloaded are 95 KB each, but they are 2.5 MB each.
I tried to build them using .net framework 4.6 but still same issue.
Any ideas?

Both are tested on 2 other PC's using windows 7/10 with .net framework 4.6

EDIT:
I changed links to download files from my own webserver (file are .zip) and everything worked fine. Previous links though work only on my PC.
Any ideas?

Ok, well my bad I didn't mention that the first links that were used come from mediafire. Though they are using captcha system that's why other users can't download the files.

Comment: The thing is that on my PC that they are developed it is working as it should. wc_DownloadProgressChanged and wc_DownloadFileCompleted
just update values on progress bar and labels.

Comment: Look inside the downloaded files with a text editor. Do they contain the RAR format or do you maybe see some error message or login screen from the server that you try to download from?

Comment: Ok well after testing that too, on my PC i download those rar's normally but other people download the page code instead of those rar's.